# GWT- Suggestbox listener not working

Tags: java, gwt, handler, suggestbox

I need to add a handler that fires when a selection is CLICKED which will then validate the value. Current functionality is validating (through textInput on blur) right before the entire value is recorded from the suggestbox, thus not passing validation (when it should).

Here is what i tried right below where i implement the suggestbox in the TextInput page:

```
public void onModuleLoad() {

SuggestBox box = new SuggestBox(createListOracle(),myTextBox());

box.addSelectionHandler(new SelectionHandler<Suggestion>() {

    @Override
    public void onSelection(SelectionEvent<Suggestion> event) {
        Validate();
    }
});
```

another solution could be to insert the courser on focus when suggestbox is selected from, that would accomplish the same thing for me.

The problem is the handler is never firing. The break-point is never reached.

Comment: This issue is actually caused by a bug in the Suggestbox, according to: http://codinginthetrenches.com/2012/catching-value-change-events-from-the-gwt-suggestbox/

Comment: However my problem is with the solution to the fix, i cant get the SelectionHandler to work as the solution says it should.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then take a look at ValueBoxBase.

You will pass your own instance to the constructor of the SuggestBox

public SuggestBox(SuggestOracle oracle, ValueBoxBase box)

TextBox is a subclass of ValueBoxBase, and it has ClickListeners so you have the choice between:

1. Create your TextBox outside and add it listeners, then pass it to the constructor SuggestBox(SuggestOracle oracle, ValueBoxBase box)
2. Overriding SuggestBox and making the constructor take a "better" ValueBoxBase (for example TextBox) and add the listener methods to your implmentation

I tried this sample, it works

```
        TextBox suggestTextBox = new TextBox();
    suggestTextBox.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            Window.alert("tada");
        }
    });
    SuggestOracle oracle = new MultiWordSuggestOracle(" ,");

    final SuggestBox nameField = new SuggestBox(oracle, suggestTextBox);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! But im not sure I understand what your telling me to do. So my file hierarchy is Widget--> TextInput--> Contains Suggestbox... when you say "create your textbox outside" do you mean to separate suggestBox from TextInput?

Comment: Also, so you do not know what could be causing the onSelection handler to not work? It seems like a popular solution to my problem, and if i could identify what could be causing it to not fire maybe that solution would be easier? I do notice that the change handler is what fires, but it takes the old value, and when the new value is  'fully' selected, nothing happens in debugger.

Comment: been trying this and many combos similar... No luck still. I can get the popup for on click, but it is applied to the textbox, so clicking in the suggestbox does not register. Also i am using SDK 2.2.0, that could also impact things...

Comment: ok nm, I got it! Actually got the onSelection to work. It wasn't working before because it was in an else if statement below another else if statement when it applied to both. So i combined them and inserted the cursor to active which works for me!

Comment: Ok Thanks for the vote. The main thing is that : "it works!" :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the advanced suggest box https://code.google.com/p/advanced-suggest-select-box/

which gives you the control over the events: you can override valueSelected() or valueTyped() and decide whether to validate it or not.

The demo of the lib is here
http://1vu-widgets.appspot.com/IntoGwt.html

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the advice but i looked into that and i think it may be pushing my resources to start from scratch. All i need is for the suggestBox to take a click listener. I don't understand why it is so hard, there must be an easy solution somewhere.