# GWT- SDK upgrade issue

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, sdk, updates

I recently came across a bug with an unresolved issue in SDK 2.2 and, as its fixed in 2.5, decided to explore a switch.

Now I am new to GWT and I have no idea of the effects of doing such a switch, but figured it couldn't hurt to mess around locally. I went ahead and successfully updated to 2.5 locally to test and can run with no errors. However many of the text boxes have changed appearance and my navigation bar disappeared, etc...

Is this type of behavior normal after an update? If so I cant imagine why anyone would be in a hurry to do so, as spending enormous amounts of time to modify all pages is pretty unrealistic. Is there maybe some type of quick fix or an error i may have made to cause this?

Comment: Well I actually went to see if it at least fixed my error, and i still have the same problem. I guess the guy that told me the issue was resolved was incorrect :( But still, what are the advantages/ disadvantages to updating the SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to put a lot of resources into a GWT project it is always a good idea to check regularly how the project is going on. On the [release-note page](http://www.gwtproject.org/release-notes.html) you can check what's new and what has been deprecated. This way you can make an informed and rational decision whenever you want to update. This is very important since going from an old version (say 1.0) to a new one (i.e 2.5.1) might give some headaches to the programmers. Spendind half-an-hour checking what's going on every month will make your life easier.

GWT has an [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/list) where you can see the open issues and what has been resolved. Many issues have never been fixed, but I read the GWT team intend to solve the 100 most important issues for the next release. GWT is now open-source and you can contribute to its development whenever you know of to fix one of those issues.

Last but not least: many people say a lot of things, which are not always correct (including on Stack Overflow). Always dubble check before making important decisions.

Giving this advice is all I can do for you so far...

Yet, if you give me some info about that bug you expected to be fixed and the exact name of that "navigation bar" widget you might find out information on the sites above to check their status. But I can't search that for you if I don't know what the bug was and the name of the widget that is broken. Also, when you say "many of the textboxes" I understand it's not every textbox that's broken but some variant your are using in some particular places. More information would also be needed...

Comment: Well the bug was a minor one with the suggestbox [Link](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=1634)         But since this route wont be a quick fix we probably will just look at another work around for it. Not sure what is up with the navigation buttons/ css that is missing. I suppose we will have to look into it further after this project. What would you say the advantages are to upgrading the SDK though? It just doesn't seem like the benefits are there to risk the client running into potential unexpected or untested areas unexpectedly.

Comment: And my post here on looking for a fix for the bug is located  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19599046/gwt-suggestbox-listener-not-working)

Comment: Advantages of updating the SDK: Updating might fix a few bugs and add a few security enhancement but you might not need it, that's true. BUT if an interesting update comes up when you are lagging behind, it will be a pain to install it. In my opinion, it's better to try to stay up-to-date. You can expect from the GWT team to run regression tests so the update won't break existing code (except if it is noted explicitely in the release notes).If the GWT team don't deliver, this is a serious issue. You should complain and consider switching to another tech if your complaint is not taken care of.

Comment: Glad someone helped you with this problem :).